# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item": possible MikTeX or package error

Tags: errors, miktex, tcolorbox

I have set up a latex preamble that generates my custom theorem boxes for definitions, theorems, lemmas etc. I copied pasted it from some guy from here and modified it slightly, and it has been working great for the last three years up until yesterday. I randomly started getting errors for putting itemize environments in the my definition environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{thmbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[top=105pt, bottom=75pt, left=75pt, right=75pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% with separate title
\xdefinecolor{thmTopColor}{RGB}{102, 102, 238}
\xdefinecolor{thmBackColor}{RGB}{245, 245, 255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newtheorem{izr}{Izrek}[section]

\newenvironment{thmbox}[1]{%
  \tcolorbox[%
  empty,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=-1pt,
  left=2ex,
  right=0ex,
  top=0ex,
  boxsep=1ex,
  before skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  colback=thmBackColor,
  colframe=white,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=thmBackColor,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=#1,
  titlerule=1pt,
  titlerule style=thmTopColor,
  overlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw[color=thmTopColor, line width=1.25pt]
    ($(frame.north west)+(.5em, -4.1ex)$)
    -- ($(frame.south west)+(.5em, 1ex)$) -- ++(2em, 0);
  }]
}{\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{izrek}[1][]{% before
  \refstepcounter{izr}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
    \begin{thmbox}{Izrek \theizr.}\itshape\hspace{-.75ex}%
  }{%
    \begin{thmbox}{Izrek \theizr%
        \hspace{.75ex}(\textnormal{#1}).}\itshape\hspace{-.75ex}
    }}
  {\end{thmbox}
}

{\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{posledica}[izr]{Posledica}
\newtheorem{trditev}[izr]{Trditev}

}

{\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[izr]{Definicija}
\newtheorem{aksiom}[izr]{Aksiom}
}

\newenvironment{noticeB}{%
  \tcolorbox[%
  notitle,
  empty,
  enhanced,  % delete the edge of the bottom page for a broken box
  breakable,
  coltext=black,
  colback=white, 
  fontupper=\rmfamily,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=-1pt,  % width of the box' edges
  frame hidden,
  left=7pt,  % inner space from text to the left edge
  right=7pt,
  top=5pt,
  bottom=5pt,
  % boxsep=0pt,
  before skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  borderline west = {1.5pt}{-0.1pt}{blue!30!black}, % second argument = offset
  overlay unbroken and last={%
    \draw[color=black, line width=1.25pt]
    ($(frame.south west)+(1.pt, -0.1pt)$) -- ++(2em, 0);
  }
  ]}
{\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{definicija}{\begin{defi}\begin{noticeB}}{%
    \end{noticeB}\end{defi}}

{\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{opomba}{Opomba}
\newtheorem*{dogovor}{Dogovor}
}

\newtheorem{zgled}[izr]{Zgled}
\tcolorboxenvironment{zgled}{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxrule=-1pt,
  colframe=gray!15,
  %borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black},  % second argument is the offset
  interior hidden,
  sharp corners,
  breakable,
  before skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=2.5ex plus 2pt
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{lema}[izr]{Lema}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lema}{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxrule=-1pt,
  sharp corners,
  colframe=white,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{orange},  % second argument is the offset
  interior hidden,
  breakable,
  before skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=2.5ex plus 2pt
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{noticeC}{%
  \tcolorbox[%
  notitle,
  empty,
  enhanced,  % delete the edge of the bottom page for a broken box
  breakable,
  coltext=black, 
  fontupper=\rmfamily,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=-1pt,  % width of the box' edges
  frame hidden,
  left=7pt,  % inner space from text to the left edge
  right=7pt,
  top=5pt,
  bottom=5pt,
  % boxsep=0pt,
  before skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=2.5ex plus 2pt,
  %borderline west = {1.5pt}{-0.1pt}{gray}, % second argument = offset
  overlay unbroken and last={%
    %\draw[color=gray, line width=1.25pt]
    %($(frame.west)$);
    %\draw[color=gray, line width=1.25pt]
    %($(frame.east)$);
  },
  ]}
{\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{dokaz}%
  {\begin{noticeC}\begin{proof}}%
  {\end{proof}\end{noticeC}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newlength\xvec@height%
\newlength\xvec@depth%
\newlength\xvec@width%
\newcommand{\xvec}[2][]{%
  \ifmmode%
    \settoheight{\xvec@height}{$#2$}%
    \settodepth{\xvec@depth}{$#2$}%
    \settowidth{\xvec@width}{$#2$}%
  \else%
    \settoheight{\xvec@height}{#2}%
    \settodepth{\xvec@depth}{#2}%
    \settowidth{\xvec@width}{#2}%
  \fi%
  \def\xvec@arg{#1}%
  \def\xvec@dd{:}%
  \def\xvec@d{.}%
  \raisebox{.2ex}{\raisebox{\xvec@height}{\rlap{%
    \kern.05em%  (Because left edge of drawing is at .05em)
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \draw (.05em,0)--(\xvec@width-.05em,0);
    \draw (\xvec@width-.05em,0)--(\xvec@width-.15em, .075em);
    \draw (\xvec@width-.05em,0)--(\xvec@width-.15em,-.075em);
    \ifx\xvec@arg\xvec@d%
      \fill(\xvec@width*.45,.5ex) circle (.5pt);%
    \else\ifx\xvec@arg\xvec@dd%
      \fill(\xvec@width*.30,.5ex) circle (.5pt);%
      \fill(\xvec@width*.65,.5ex) circle (.5pt);%
    \fi\fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}}%
  #2%
}
\makeatother

% --- Override \vec with an invocation of \xvec.
\let\stdvec\vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\xvec[]{#1}}
% --- Define \dvec and \ddvec for dotted and double-dotted vectors.
\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\xvec[.]{#1}}
\newcommand{\ddvec}[1]{\xvec[:]{#1}}
\newcommand{\stcomp}[1]{{#1}^{\mathsf{c}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb {N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb {Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb {Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb {R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb {C}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb {F}}
\newcommand{\Ha}{\mathbb {H}}
\newcommand{\zap}[1]{(#1_n)_{n=1} ^{\infty}}
\newcommand{\podzap}[1]{(#1_{n_j})_{n=1 ^{\infty}}}
\newcommand{\limzap}[1]{\lim_{n \to \infty} {#1}}
\newcommand{\limf}[3]{\lim_{#1 \to #2} {#3}}
\newcommand{\rlimf}[3]{\lim_{#1 \downarrow #2} {#3}}
\newcommand{\llimf}[3]{\lim_{#1 \uparrow #2} {#3}}
\newcommand{\quot}[2]{{\raisebox{0em}{$#1$}\left/\raisebox{0em}{$#2$}\right.}}
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}
\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{im}\,}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}\,}
\newcommand{\gal}[1]{\mathrm{Gal}\, {\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\chara}{\mathrm{char}\, }
\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{izrek}
    Naj bo $M$ $R$-modul. Naslednje tri trditve so ekvivalentne:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item $M$ je prost.
      \item $M$ je izomorfen (lahko tudi neskončni) direktni vsoti kopij kolobarja $R$.
      \item $M = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \Lambda} M_\lambda$, kjer je $M_\lambda \leq M$ in $M_\lambda \cong R.$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{izrek}

  \begin{definicija}
    Naj bosta $M$ in $N$ $R$-modula in $F$ prosti $R$-modul
    z bazo $X = M \times N$ (kartezični produkt množic).
    Naj bo $T$ podmodul v $F$, generiran z naslednjimi elementi:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $(m_1 + m_2, n) -(m_1, n) - (m_2, n)$ za $m_1, m_2 \in M$ in $n \in N$.
      \item $(m, n_1 + n_2) - (m, n_1) - (m, n_2)$ za $m \in M$ in $n_1, n_2 \in N$.
      \item $(rm, n) - r(m, n)$ za $r \in R$, $m \in M$, $n \in N$.
      \item $(m, rn) - r(m, n)$ za $r \in R$, $m \in M$, $n \in N$.
    \end{itemize}
    $R$-modulu $\quot{F}{T}$ pravimo tenzorski produkt modulov $M$ in $N$ in ga 
    označimo s 
    $$\quot{F}{T} = M \otimes_R N.$$
  \end{definicija}

\end{document}
```

The environment "izrek" works properly, but the environment "definicija" gives me an error
"Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" on line 296. This is the only error that I get.
This is incredibly frustrating because all the documents that have been successfully compiled over the last few years suddenlygive me the same errors whenever I put itemize inside the "definicija" environment. The other thing is that the errors are not reproducible - the code above runs just fine on my other computer. I've tried to uninstall and install MikTeX a few times, but to no avail. I desperately need a solution, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you certainly copied a lot of information form "some guy" ;-P. The problem isn't in the MikTeX distribution. The error is caused by some line inside your definitions and should be traceable. Do you use PDFLaTeX of LuaLaTeX to compile? It helps me to help you trace the error.

Comment: Can you share the configuration and OS of both computers? Since one doesn't show the errors and the other does, a small difference can be a clue to track the issue.

Comment: I use pdflatex, both of my computers have windows.

Comment: @alchemist I also forgot that up until yesterday, I was able to compile all the documents with this exact preamble on this computer without any errors. I figured that the problem was because I had to update some package or something like that, but I honestly don't know anymore.

Comment: that is a known issue: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/199

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why is this error occuring only in "definicija" environment, and not for example in "izrek"?

Comment: izrek has no theorem and so no trivlist around the tcolorbox. You get the error only with "list around tcolorbox around list", and not with "tcolorbox around list".